# Why this works? onLayoutChangeListener works inversely

Tags: android

I want my layout's weight changed when softkeyboard disappear/appear.

like

case : disapper -> layout's weight = 6

case : apper -> layout's weight = 10

so I add onlayoutChangeListener, but it works strangely.

when if(bottom

and if(bottom>oldBottom) works like that too.

to sum up, onLayoutChangeListener works inversely.

```
relativelayout_wrap_content.addOnLayoutChangeListener(
            new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
                        int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(bottom<oldBottom && (bottom!=oldBottom) )
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.mainactivity_context, "bottom<oldBottom\n"+"bottom:"+bottom+"\noldBottom:"+oldBottom, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        relativelayout_wrap_content.setLayoutParams(
                                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,6.0f));



                    }
                    else if(bottom>oldBottom && (bottom!=oldBottom)  && isSoftKeyboardShown)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.mainactivity_context, "bottom>oldBottom\n"+"bottom:"+bottom+"\noldBottom:"+oldBottom, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        relativelayout_wrap_content.setLayoutParams(
                                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,10.0f));
                    }
                }
            });



edittext_free_reple.setOnFocusChangeListener(
            new OnFocusChangeListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(hasFocus)
                    {
                        isSoftKeyboardShown = true;
                        relativelayout_wrap_content.setLayoutParams(
                                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,10.0f));
                    }


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The left top of the screen is (0,0). So the bottom must be lesser than the oldBottom if the softKeyBoard shown. That is (bottom

```
 if(bottom<oldBottom && (bottom!=oldBottom) )
{
//when the keyboard shown
}
else if(bottom>oldbottom)
{
//when the keyboard hidden
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question, but I mean my code works  
if(bottom<oldBottom && (bottom!=oldBottom) )
{
//when the keyboard hidden
}
else if(bottom>oldbottom)
{
//when the keyboard shown
}